# Create SIGINT (Signal Interrupt) Shortcut for iTerm2

Tags: macos, iterm2

How can I create a shortcut to send a signal interrupt in iTerm2? 
 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is the default, but I would like to have <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (dot/period) send a break signal as it currently does in Terminal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Preferences » Keys » Key Bindings

1. click <kbd>+</kbd>
2. Action: *Send Hex Code*
3. enter `0x03`

[image]

Comment: In case you're looking for other Ctrl+ keycodes, you can find the list here https://www.physics.udel.edu/~watson/scen103/ascii.html

Answer (score -1):

I wish ctrl+c was the default. somehow I need to use Fn + Ctrl + C and it does not work with attached keyboard. Help! Where can I set it globally to the entire os?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Kindly remove this, as it's not an answer and adds noise to the main topic